# How to define a cube unit based on Graphics3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, list-manipulation

I would like to ask,how can we draw 50 spheres of radius **0.1** (randomly) in the **unit cube**.

This is my first try,

```
Graphics3D[
 Table[{Red, Sphere[RandomReal[{0.1, 0.9}, 3], 0.1]}, {50}], 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

To define a unit cube is this enough???

Comment: Looks like this is a question from the quiz questions for the Wolfram-U "Programming Fundamentals Week 4" course [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1985992).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine.

A few alternatives you might consider:

1. You can generate random centers using a single call to `RandomReal`:

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[RandomReal[{0.1, 0.9}, {50, 3}], 0.1]}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

2. You can transform `Cuboid[]` and use it with [`RandomPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html) as follows:

```
r = .1;

transformedCuboid = Cuboid[r {1, 1, 1}, (1 - r) {1, 1, 1}];

centers = RandomPoint[transformedCuboid, 30];

Graphics3D[{PointSize[Medium], Point@centers, 
  Opacity[.5, Red], Sphere[#, r] & /@ centers, 
  EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[], Cuboid[], 
  EdgeForm[Green], transformedCuboid}]
```

[image]

Comment: what is the error in my proposed code?

Comment: can we fine the color inside the command "Sphere"?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, I don't see any error in your code.